# "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint” when Inserting in database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm trying to insert a record in database from a winform it was working fine and insert first 5 records with no error but when i try to insert next record it give me the error of Violation of PRIMARY KEY....!

The table is

[image]
But in Database table there is not record of no 6.
There is no trigger associate to this table.
there is no F-Key relationship of that table.
I tried it from sql server to insert it but again error.
What is the reason behind it?

Comment: can you show your tables?

Comment: Check the PK of 6th record you are trying to insert. seems like 6th record uses one of the existing PK value.

Comment: @accessdenied I use SELECT statement to check the record exist or not.. but there is no record.

Comment: Please show us the data you have, and the INSERT you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely something wrong with your data. Please make sure you don't have a "duplicated PK" inserted.

And in my opinion, the PK should be generated automatically unless you have some special requirements.

Comment: @ Colt the primary key is autogenerated

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this error by not trying to insert rows with a duplicate primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key should be auto generated.if you are getting this error then check your data first.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key musty be inserted in table by itself, as this also reduces the code error chances that sometimes we try to insert same key again and again, (which is not the property of PK).

Also in database:

```
 table> design> Primary Key> Properties>Identity specification> Yes
```

This will enable self insertion of key, also you can specify start index.